# Best book to learn probability from

Tags: probability

People I need your help, I suck at probability and statistics a lot. I have tried to but I am unable to grasp simple concepts and now I am asking for help. I need either videos like George B. Thomas videos on calculus. I can understand him but sadly I am unable to understand from any other source I have tired and tried and now I am tired of being such a dumb. Please help either a book or videos on undergraduate level probability.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have been co-teaching undergraduate probability theory and statistics on several courses both on Bachelor and Master level. Generally I think it is a good idea to have the end goal of such studies very clear in mind when starting out. That is, if you are about to become a researcher in probability and statistics you might take one approach, if you are/or will be using a very specific set of techniques in your daily work you might take another.

Here are my recommendations, that some student have found helpful, for some scenarios:

1. You study/work with something that involves using and interpreting the result of some very restricted set of statistical methods.

Recommendation:
Take the free Khan academy course on [probability and statistics](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/probability-library), and any other resource on their site that might suit you, they cover a lot of statistics and it keeps growing. Look on youtube for clips explaining the theory behind the specific methods you use. E.g. for clips concerning the probability theory behind econometrics/time series analysis see the eminent clips of [Ben Lambert](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=benlambert). You might not need a book in this scenario. If you feel that you do, I would generally avoid too field-specific books such as [this](https://books.google.se/books?id=2sSojW_5vwIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=probability%20and%20statistics%20for%20psychology&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_9rHc_JjaAhUEUlAKHYutDjUQ6AEIWDAG#v=onepage&q=probability%20and%20statistics%20for%20psychology&f=false), as they are, in my opinion, often too narrow for the general understanding of the underlying theory, making you have to consult more advanced books anyway. Instead, if you feel the need for a book I recommend the book for the second scenario, even though it contains a lot more than you need.

2. You are going to/are working with several statistical methods and wants to be able to understand/compare the differences between related methods, perhaps even understand some basic derivations/proofs of some methods.

Recommendation:
Start with the recommendations for scenario 1. After that I would recommend the book [Mathematical statistics with applications](https://books.google.se/books?id=lTgGAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=mathematical%20statistics%20with%20applications%20/&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnsZWC_5jaAhXJZ1AKHSBGCC0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=mathematical%20statistics%20with%20applications%20%2F&f=false). This book is used for several bachelor-level courses on my university and contains a lot of basics, yet it lies a solid foundation for more advanced stuff. I would read this book in parallel with the more advanced probability theory book [An Intermediate Course in Probability](https://books.google.se/books?id=o5buBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=alan%20gut%20probbaility&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWmu-agZnaAhVIJVAKHa6CAisQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=alan%20gut%20probbaility&f=false) and the inference book [Statistical Inference](https://books.google.se/books?id=ZpkPPwAACAAJ&dq=Casella%20berger%20inference&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikgo3GgZnaAhWSPFAKHWb-AC8Q6AEIKDAA). I generally recommend reading inference in parallel with probability theory from an early stage, as for most people applying statistical methods, the probability theory is often mostly needed to understand the inference and the properties thereof. With the three mentioned books you can come from a very shallow understanding of prob to deriving and proving some really advanced stuff without any additional sources.

3. You are beginning you knowledge journey towards a research carrier in statistics and probability theory.

Recommendation: I recommend you to approach probability from the math perspective starting with measure theory right away. This will take a lot more time, depending on your math skills, but will be worth it as soon as things become advanced. I did not take this route and I often regret it. As I did not take this route I cannot recommend books, however I would consult what books the large universities are using in their intro to measure theory as a starting point. I find the continuation to the [previously mentioned](https://books.google.se/books?id=o5buBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=alan%20gut%20probbaility&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWmu-agZnaAhVIJVAKHa6CAisQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=alan%20gut%20probbaility&f=false) book [Probability : an introduction](https://books.google.se/books?id=i7OacQAACAAJ&dq=alan%20gut%20probbaility%20graduate&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjasNqzhJnaAhWIQpoKHU-qA6cQ6AEIKjAA) really useful, although it is heavy reading without a solid mathematical background.

A final general advice is to ask someone who deals with the same type of probability/statistics that you are, and seem to understand it better, what they have found helpful. One of the most difficult things when learning something as wide as probability and statistics is how to prioritize, something that is difficult to give advice on without the a specified end goal.

Comment: Let me be very specific I am studying digital signal and image processing and for this field probability is the key to generate random signals and noise. Now I will use the keyword through which I think will have an idea of what I am looking for, and the keyword is gaussian nosie, white noise and mixed random variables.

Comment: Then I think the recommendations for the second scenario applies, but I would also [add this book](https://books.google.se/books?id=lJsTPzo37tAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Probability,+random+variables,+and+random+processes:+theory+and+signal+processing+applications&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmwbnjnZ7aAhWNZFAKHQ3FBdEQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Probability%2C%20random%20variables%2C%20and%20random%20processes%3A%20theory%20and%20signal%20processing%20applications&f=false) to get the specific applications. I've found it useful as a supplement when taking master level machine learning courses.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked Sheldon Ross' A First Course in Probability. Very readable with exercises that follow naturally from the material.